# Cosa significa "bumpete"? È una parola piana o sdrucciola?

Tags: word-meaning, pronunciation, accents

Nella commedia *Morte accidentale di un anarchico*, di Dario Fo, a un certo momento il personaggio del Matto dice

> **Bumpete**... È arrivato l'avvoltoio!

come commento a quello che ha spiegato prima una giornalista. La mia domanda è sul significato di "bumpete" in questo brano. Non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Si tratta di un vocabolo di origine dialettale?

Questa parola è piana o sdrucciola?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. È un suono onomatopeico (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopea).
"Bump" anche nei fumetti indica di solito una collisione, o meglio il suono emesso a seguito di una caduta o un tonfo.

In questo caso viene utilizzato credo in modo sarcastico per indicare che  la giornalista è piombata all'improvviso alle sue conclusioni come un avvoltoio.

Sim. "Patapumfete" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2AQL_69QNU).

Questo tipo di onomatopee sono utilizzate di solito per dare enfasi, oppure (come nel filmato e nel brano citato) per accentuare un significato di sfottò o sarcastico ed hanno una pronuncia sdrucciola.

Es. "Zac" (suono delle forbici) -> "zàcchete" (http://treccani.it/vocabolario/zacchete).

Quindi la pronuncia è "bùmpete" / "patapùmfete", ecc.

Comment: Con il termine "avvoltoio" il Matto si riferisce alla giornalista.

Comment: Ho editato la mia risposta in modo che sia più pertinente.

Comment: Capisco. È molto curiosa però questa terminazione in "-ete".

Comment: Come nell'esempio del video, la sento utilizzare spesso soprattutto per accentuare un significato sarcastico/sfottò.

"Zac" (suono delle forbici) -> "zàcchete"
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/zacchete/ (in questo caso citato dalla Treccani serve a dare maggior enfasi).

Comment: Interessante... E la pronuncia è sdrucciola? Aggiungo questo alla domanda, OK?

Comment: Corretto :) La pronuncia è sdrucciola :) pùmfete

Comment: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta? Siccome è una parola che non si trova nel dizionario... Io tendo a immaginare sempre una pronuncia piana.