# Qual è l'origine del suffisso "-ete" nelle onomatopee?

Tags: etymology, regional, suffix

Leggendo [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7855/4679), mi sono interrogata sull'origine del suffisso "-ete" nelle onomatopee ("bumpete", come nella domanda, ma anche "zacchete"). Un uso illustre è dato da Aldo Palazzeschi nella sua poesia *La fontana malata* (1909):

> Clof, clop, cloch, 
>   **cloffete,
>
>   cloppete,
>
>   clocchete,**
>   chchch...
>   È giù,
>   nel cortile,
>   la povera
>   fontana
>   malata; [...]

A quando risale la sua prima attestazione? È di origine regionale?

A me verrebbe da pensare che abbia un'origine romana e che si formi come "ammappete" e "aridanghete", ma non trovo fonti che lo dimostrino.

**Edit:** Sembra che il suffisso -ete sia [diffuso in triestino](http://ricerca.gelocal.it/ilpiccolo/archivio/ilpiccolo/2013/05/07/NZ_50_02.html):

> Tipicamente triestino per dire "in quattro e quattr'otto" è il tic e tac e ancora più tipico è il tichete tachete, che manifesta in maniera evidente una predilezione per il finale in -ete. L'italiano ha quasi solo "patapunfete", noi invece con quel -ete pare ci siamo specializzati nel… colpo con rimbalzo, perché abbiamo zachete (il taglio netto) e trachete (lo spezzarsi di qualcosa) e poi s'ciachete, pafete, clunchete, sgnachete.

Comment: Domanda interessante! Quanto all'aggiunta, del triestino non so niente, ma in italiano standard c'è ben più che “patapunfete”. Da una ricerca sullo Zingarelli ne risultano registrati vari: ciacchete, ciuffete, clanghete, clocchete, cloppete e così via.

Comment: Sul Tommaseo-Bellini ce ne sono di meno, ma pur sempre una mezza dozzina: pàffete, tònfete, tòppete...

Comment: Istintivamente, direi che si tratti di due "varietà" diverse dello stesso suono. Per esempio, per me "clop" rappresenta il suono di uno zoccolo che batte sulla strada ma il suono di un cavallo che cammina o trotta è diverso perché i "clop" si susseguono e sovrappongono originando un "cloppete-cloppete", più che un "clop-clop". Lo stesso vale per molti altri suoni che risultano leggermente diversi quando sono isolati o in sequenza ed i cui l'aggiunta di quell'-ete funziona come una legatura. Lo stesso discorso vale per l'eco: all'aperto le mani fanno "clap", sotto una volta fanno "clappete"